# jQuery.data() working only for appended elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

In jQuery documentation ([jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)) examples are regarding "data" assigned to elements that are already appended to document, like this

```
<script>var div = $("div")[0];
    jQuery.data(div, "test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
    $("span:first").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").first);
    $("span:last").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").last);
</script>
```

I've tried to assign data in the same way, but to a yet NOT appended object, like this

```
<script>var div = $("<div></div>")[0];
    jQuery.data(div, "test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
    $("span:first").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").first);
    $("span:last").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").last);
</script>
```

It does not work. Should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[0]`, works in latest jquery Release

```
<script>var div = $("<div></div>");
    jQuery.data(div, "test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
    $("span:first").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").first);
    $("span:last").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").last);
</script>
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsa7D/1/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I have just updated the code, and it is not working for me.. Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/strategycon/HT5tf/1/

Comment: you're working with local variables which contents are gone when the event is executed again: see http://jsfiddle.net/wEVyU/1/